# Flattern object in nested array of arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays, which contain objects, would like to get the value of a certain key and return it as a big array, have tried a nested map but it returns multiple array's rather than a single array.

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    sub_items: [
      {
        id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    sub_items: [
      {
        id: 4
      },
      {
        id: 5
      },
      {
        id: 6
      }
    ]
  }
]

const subItemIDs = items.map( (item) =>
  item.sub_items.map( (subItem) => subItem.id )
)

console.log(subItemIDs);
```

Expected output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Actual output

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
```

Comment: what should be the output looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `arrays.flat()`. I can provide more specific code once output is mentioned in the question

```
const arr1 = [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]];

console.log(arr1.flat());
// expected output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

const arr2 = [0, 1, 2, [[[3, 4]]]];

console.log(arr2.flat(2));
// expected output: [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get a flat array from nested arrays.

```js
const
    items = [{ id: 1, sub_items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] }, { id: 2, sub_items: [{ id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }] }],
    subItemIDs = items.flatMap(({ sub_items }) => sub_items.map(({ id }) => id));

console.log(subItemIDs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Achieved this with:

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    sub_items: [
      {
        id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    sub_items: [
      {
        id: 4
      },
      {
        id: 5
      },
      {
        id: 6
      }
    ]
  }
]

const subItemIDs = [].concat(...items.map( (item) =>
  item.sub_items.map( (subItem) => subItem.id )
))

console.log(subItemIDs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the obvious is the easiest:
Given a data structure that looks like this

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, sub_items: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, ] },
  { id: 2, sub_items: [ { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, ] },
];
```

A trivial function like this

```js
function extract_item_ids( items ) {
  const ids = [];
  for ( const item of items ) {
    for ( const {id} of sub_items ) {
      ids.push(id);
    }
  }
  return ids;
}
```

should do the trick. If you want to collect the ids from a tree of any depth, it's just as easy:

```json
function extract_item_ids( items ) {
  const ids = [];

  const pending = items;
  while ( pending.length > 0 ) {
    const item = pending.pop();

    ids.push(item.id);
    pending.push(...( item.sub_items || [] ) );

  }

  return ids;
}
```

And collecting the set of discrete item IDs is no more difficult:
If you want to collect the ids from a tree of any depth, it's just as easy:

```json
function extract_item_ids( items ) {
  const ids = new Set();

  const pending = [...items];
  while ( pending.length > 0 ) {
    const item = pending.pop();

    ids.add(item.id);
    pending.push(...( item.sub_items || [] ) );

  }

  return Array.from(ids);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As is the case with most things JavaScript, you have several options.  Some are more efficient than others, others have a certain stylistic purity, others might better speak to your fancy.  Here are a few:

### Array.flat

With array flat you can take your original code and have the JS Engine flatten the array down to a one-dimensional array.  Simply append `.flat()` onto the end of your map.

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, sub_items: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, ] },
  { id: 2, sub_items: [ { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, ] },
];

const subItemIds = items.map( (item) =>
  item.sub_items.map( (subItem) => subItem.id )
).flat()

console.log(subItemIds);
```

### Array.reduce

Another method is to use reduce to iterate over the object and build an accumulation array using `Array.reduce`.  In the example below, when pushing onto the array, the spread operator (`...`) is used to break the array into elements.

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, sub_items: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, ] },
  { id: 2, sub_items: [ { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, ] },
];

const subItemIds = items.reduce((arr,item) => (
   arr.push(...item.sub_items.map((subItem) => subItem.id)), arr
),[])

console.log(subItemIds);
```

### Other

Other answers here make use of custom functions or `Array.flatMap`, which should be explored as they could lead to more readable and efficient code, depending on the program's needs.